# Spring boot @Autowired is not working in the servlet duriing the server startup

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have servlet whose load on startup property is '1', in this servlet I have to cache database entries during the application server startup.
In this servlet I am calling the CacheService which retrieves the db objects, its annotated with @Autowired annoatation, during the application startup the CacheService object is null.I have annotated the CacheService with @Service annotation. The @Autowired annotation is not working.

```
@Service
public class CacheService {
    @Autowired
    private IJobsService jobsServiceImpl; 
    public List<Jobs> getALLJobs(){
        List<Jobs> alljobs = jobsServiceImpl.findAllJobs();
        return alljobs;
    }

}


public class StartupServlet extends HttpServlet {

       @Autowired
       private CacheService cacheService; -- object is null not autowired
}

Below is the main class


@EnableCaching
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.example.demo.repository"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.example.demo.entity"})
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.example.demo"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
        org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
        org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class})

public class DemoApplication  extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
       protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
          return builder.sources(DemoApplication.class);
       }

     @Bean
        ServletRegistrationBean myServletRegistration () {
            ServletRegistrationBean srb = new ServletRegistrationBean();
            srb.setServlet(new StartupServlet());
            srb.setUrlMappings(Arrays.asList("/path2/*"));
            srb.setLoadOnStartup(1);
            return srb;
        }
}
```

Could some body help me on this...?

Comment: Why do you use a servlet to do that? Just do it in the PostConstruct of a regular singleton bean.

Comment: @JBNizet  does the method annotated with PostConstruct executes during server startup ?

Comment: Your servlet is not a spring managed bean. There is autowiring not possible

Comment: @Jens any way to make it spring managed or any other approach i have to work out, kindly suggest

Comment: Read about spring mvc

Comment: Spring starts up at startup, and it thus creates the beans.

Comment: Make sure that CatcheService class is inside com.example.demo package since it looks for @ComponentScan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do some additional work for this. You have to talk to `beanFactory`-like spring component and ask it to make that particular instance an eligible bean. `AutowireCapableBeanFactory` should do the trick.

Here is a simple example based on code you have provided

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So44734879Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So44734879Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Bean
    ServletRegistrationBean myServletRegistration() {
        ServletRegistrationBean srb = new ServletRegistrationBean();
        final StartupServlet servlet = new StartupServlet();
        beanFactory.autowireBean(servlet);  // <--- The most important part
        srb.setServlet(servlet);
        srb.setUrlMappings(Arrays.asList("/path2/*"));
        srb.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        return srb;
    }

    @Bean
    MyService myService() {
        return new MyService();
    }

    public static class MyService {
        String time() {
            return "Time: " + System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }

    public static class StartupServlet extends HttpServlet {
        @Autowired
        MyService myService;

        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
            final PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
            writer.write(myService.time());
            writer.close();
        }
    }
}
```

=>

```
$ curl -XGET localhost:8080/path2
Time: 1498299772141%
```

Comment: Make sure that CatcheService class is inside com.example.demo package since it looks for @ComponentScan

Answer (score 2):

You're creating the servlet by using `new` so you need to provide its dependencies. Since you're using a mix of annotation and java code configuration you can accomplish it like this:

```
public class StartupServlet extends HttpServlet {

  private CacheService cacheService;

  public StartupServlet(CacheService cacheService) {
    this.cacheService = cacheService;
  }

  // ... rest of servlet
}
```

Main class:

```
   @Bean
   ServletRegistrationBean myServletRegistration (CacheService cacheService) { // <<<--- cacheService will be provided here by Spring because it's annotated
        ServletRegistrationBean srb = new ServletRegistrationBean();
        srb.setServlet(new StartupServlet(cacheService));
        srb.setUrlMappings(Arrays.asList("/path2/*"));
        srb.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        return srb;
    }
```